# ASP.NET MVC : action link to simple pages in the root directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got menu in my ASP MVC project, and can when I use

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink("My", "My")%></li>
```

it redirects me to .../Home/My
and if I got

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink("My", "My", "ZZZ")%></li>
```

it redirects me to .../ZZZ/My

the problem is I've got some pages out of MVC , with simple Inherits and they are in the root so I need to got to **/My.aspx**

How can I redirect to /My.aspx in my MVC menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActionLink method looks up the MVC routing information to generate the URL, but by default WebForm pages are not set up with routing, they are file based, so I don't think you can use the ActionLink method for this purpose.